Couple captured by aliens, man slowly becomes a cyborg?
I don't know when the film was made but it was on TV in the 90's (I was really young then). This memory has been bugging me a few months now and I would like to find out what the movie was called and potentially watch it again. Been researching on the web but no luck.
In the movie there was a man and a woman (maybe more but I don't remember them if so) was locked up or captured by some alien race. The guy was slowing modify into some sort of "cyborg". There was some romance between the couple and every time they meet he's changed a little bit. Also there was some alien food which look like a lobster? It was just throw inside the "prison cell" for then to eat.

It's not a 100% match, but you are probably thinking of The Outer Limits episode Quality of Mercy, (1995).  It is the woman, not the man, who is being modified:

Major John Skokes has been captured by the seemingly unbeatable aliens
  currently warring on Earth. His companion is a young Cadet captured on
  a training flight, Bree Tristan. Skokes must find a way out of the
  dank prison for himself and his fellow prisoner before the aliens
  succeed in converting her to one of their own species!


It very similar but not the one, great episode tho. The scene in my memory was a man been modified and set in a ship? The changes done to him was more "cyborg" looking (no it not star trek).

That was a wonderful episode. was there not a typical sting in the tail of that episode?

Can you recall anything about the physical appearance of the characters?
Have you tried the show Lexx?
Image of a cyborg character from the show named Mantrid, as one example

The sole purpose of the Cluster's legal system was to procure flesh
  from His Divine Shadow's unfortunate subjects, with death or forced
  organ donation being the primary means of punishment. This flesh would
  then be contributed to the 'Protein Bank', where it would be used to
  feed either the Lexx or the Gigashadow, or used in the creation of
  cyborgs. from Wikipeadia

